# How to separate an array into two arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. I want to remove Fields which have columns has null. It has to separate into two different arrays which has columns data another has does not have columns

```
const groupItems = [
    {
        "GroupName": "CorrSection",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldName": "TemplateVersion",
                "Columns": null
            },
            {
                "FieldName": "CorrTypePrintGrps",
                "Columns": [
                    {
                        "ColumnName": "CorrTypeName"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupName": "RcSection",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldName": "RcVersion",
                "Columns": null
            },
            {
                "FieldName": "RcPrintGrps",
                "Columns": [
                    {
                        "ColumnName": "RcName"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to filter the objects but unable to get parent object along with it, to be precise GroupName is missing

```
groupItems.map(item=>item.Fields.filter(k=>k.Columns!==null))
```

I am expecting two different arrays as output

Array_One

```
[
    {
        "GroupName": "CorrSection",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldName": "TemplateVersion",
                "Columns": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupName": "RcSection",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldName": "RcVersion",
                "Columns": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Array_Two

```
[
    {
        "GroupName": "CorrSection",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldName": "CorrTypePrintGrps",
                "Columns": [
                    {
                        "ColumnName": "CorrTypeName"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupName": "RcSection",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldName": "RcPrintGrps",
                "Columns": [
                    {
                        "ColumnName": "RcName"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map with destructuring to extract fields:

```js
const groupItems = [
    {
        "GroupName": "CorrSection",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldName": "TemplateVersion",
                "Columns": null
            },
            {
                "FieldName": "CorrTypePrintGrps",
                "Columns": [
                    {
                        "ColumnName": "CorrTypeName"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupName": "RcSection",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "FieldName": "RcVersion",
                "Columns": null
            },
            {
                "FieldName": "RcPrintGrps",
                "Columns": [
                    {
                        "ColumnName": "RcName"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]


const arr1 = groupItems.map(({ GroupName, Fields }) => ({
  GroupName,
  Fields: Fields.filter(({ Columns }) => Columns === null)
}));

const arr2 = groupItems.map(({ GroupName, Fields }) => ({
  GroupName,
  Fields: Fields.filter(({ Columns }) => Columns !== null)
}));


console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```